# How align correctely components on UIView in Swift Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, constraints

I'am trying make a table for bitcoin values of poloniex.com. I align the components with the mouse, until it was good, but not perfect and there is a slight misalignment of the components, especially in the headers and their table contents. Also, when I use "Reset to suggest constraints," to stay the same on all screen sizes of an error at the time the screen refreshes and nothing appears.

This is the correct view, without suggest constraints.
[image]

My screen
[image]

So, when I use suggested constraints:

[image]

And, this error appears:

```
 [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 

        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 

        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 

(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400009f720 cellCoin.lastBaseline == cellPrice.lastBaseline   (active, names: cellCoin:0x7fa245e17be0, cellPrice:0x7fa245e183a0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400009f770 cellCoin.firstBaseline == cellPrice.firstBaseline   (active, names: cellCoin:0x7fa245e17be0, cellPrice:0x7fa245e183a0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400009f7c0 cellCoin.centerY == UIView:0x7fa245e17a00.centerY   (active, names: cellCoin:0x7fa245e17be0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400009f860 V:|-(3)-[cellCoin]   (active, names: cellCoin:0x7fa245e17be0, '|':UIView:0x7fa245e17a00 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400009fb30 V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7fa245e17a00]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fa245e173e0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400009fb80 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fa245e173e0.bottomMargin == UIView:0x7fa245e17a00.bottom + 13   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000280320 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fa245e173e0.height == 19.5   (active)>"
)
```

EDIT: Added image of constraints.
[image]

Comment: show your constraints

Comment: show your constraints of cell elements on storyboard

Comment: I think that's it...I did edited.